# How to jump to Javascript function definition in vim?

Tags: javascript, vim, plugins

I'm using vim with the tagbar, jsctags and taglist-plus plugins. They all seem to work correctly, but I cannot jump to a function/variable declaration. I tried ctrl+] but it doesn't work. Is it possible to setup vim so that you can jump to a function or variable declaration?

Comment: Assuming youre defining your functions and variables with `var name =`... could you not just `:/var\ name` ?

Comment: I guess that could work, but it would be easier if I could just press a shortcut key to find it just like for functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without needing jsctags, I have the following in my ~/.ctags for handling JavaScript correctly:

```
--regex-JavaScript=/([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ \t]*[:=][ \t]*new[ \t]+Object\(/\1/o,object/                                                                                             
--regex-JavaScript=/([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ \t]*[:=][ \t]*\{/\1/o,object/
--regex-JavaScript=/([A-Za-z0-9._$()]+)[ \t]*[:=][ \t]*function[ \t]*\(/\1/f,function/
--regex-JavaScript=/function[ \t]+([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ \t]*\([^\]\)]*\)/\1/f,function/
--regex-JavaScript=/([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ \t]*[:=][ \t]*new[ \t]+Array\(/\1/a,array/
--regex-JavaScript=/([A-Za-z0-9._$]+)[ \t]*[:=][ \t]*\[/\1/a,array/
--regex-JavaScript=/([^= ]+)[ \t]*=[ \t]*[^""]'[^'']*/\1/s,string/
--regex-JavaScript=/([^= ]+)[ \t]*=[ \t]*[^'']"[^""]*/\1/s,string/
```

Using the above, a simple `ctags -R` generates the appropriate tagfile to match JavaScript function (and variable and object) definitions.

Comment: I tried that and it's still not able to jump to function definitions.

Comment: @javascriptninja And you regenerated your tag file after adding these?

Comment: @javascriptninja Check `man ctags` in the `FILES` section to be sure your version accepts `$HOME/.ctags` or other user-config files.

Comment: OK I found out that it works for some functions, but it doesn't work for any variables. I checked and it does use that as a config file.

Answer (score 3):

TagBar and TagList don't generate the actual `tags` file used by Vim to jump to definitions.

If you want this ability to jump you have to generate this file manually from the terminal:

```
$ ctags -R .
```

if you use `ctags` or:

```
$ jsctags .
```

if you use `jsctags` or from Vim itself.